# Using Wildcards in Field Names of multi_match Query to match the whole fields

Tags: elasticsearch

[Using Wildcards in Field Names](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-match-query.html#_using_wildcards_in_field_names) says field names can be specified with wildcards, for example:

```
{
    "multi_match": {
        "query":  "Quick brown fox",
        "fields": "*_title"
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to query among all fields in the index, So I tried to use `*` to match all fields. But I got an error, for example:

```
{
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "nanjing jianye",
      "fields": ["*"]
    }
}
```

error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Invalid format: \"nanjing jianye\""
         }
      ],
      "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
      "reason": "all shards failed",
      "phase": "query",
      "grouped": true,
      "failed_shards": [
         {
            "shard": 0,
            "index": "mycustomer",
            "node": "YHKU1KllRJW-BiH9g5-McQ",
            "reason": {
               "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
               "reason": "Invalid format: \"nanjing jianye\""
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

How to match the whole fields using wildcards instead of explicitly specifying the fields?

Comment: have you tried to use the `"_all"` field instead of `"*"`?

Comment: Yes. It works, but in my opinion, using `"_all"` field will become `cross fields` query. What I want is `best fields` query.

Comment: How many fields do you have? If not too many, probably enumerate them all. Test that and then `_all` and check which approach suits you best.

Comment: I even want to query among many indices. So enumerating them all isn't good for this.